Map & filter table data
Existing code:
{categorizedDatas2[key]?.items.map((item, index) => {
    if (item.packingLocation == 'A') {
        return (
            <>
                <Table>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>{item.packingLocation}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>{item.Name}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </Table>
            </>
        )
    }
    if (item.packingLocation == 'B') {
        return (
            <>
                <Table>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>{item.packingLocation}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>{item.Name}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </Table>
            </>
        )
    }
})}

What I actually want to do is map through and do a table for each packingLocation (currently as it is in a map it shows the packingLocation on each row) How can I use the map and utilise a filter function so it filters out for packingLocation equal A and then shows the table, and then another table for packingLocation equal B and so forth...

Do you want items with the same packingLocation in the same <Table> or each item in its own <Table>?

You can do that simply with these steps.
Step 1,
You can provide all your packingLocation inside an array like this
const packingLocations = ['A', 'B']; // provide all locations.

OR
Step 1b. You can also make use of set if you don't want duplicates
const uniquePackingLocations = [...new Set(categorizedDatas2[key]?.items.map(item => item.packingLocation))];

Step 2, use filter items for the current locations.
uniquePackingLocations.map((location) => {
  // Filter items for the current packingLocation
  const filteredItems = categorizedDatas2[key]?.items.filter(item => item.packingLocation === location);

  if (filteredItems?.length) {
    return (
      <Table key={location}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Packing Location</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {filteredItems.map((item, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell>{item.packingLocation}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.Name}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
  return null; // if there is no item to render


This is perfect - on the const filteredItems how can I sort those A-Z?

You have to groupBy your object array on property packingLocation.
you can use helper function to create the group object and then use the newly created object array.
Here is the modified version of your code.
const groupedByLocation = categorizedDatas2[key]?.itemsitems.reduce((group, item) => {
const { packingLocation } = item;
if (!group[packingLocation]) {
    group[packingLocation] = [];  // Initialize array if it doesn't exist
}
group[packingLocation].push(item);  // Add the item to the array
    return group;
}, {});

and then use it like this
Object.keys(groupedByLocation).map((key,i) => {
    const items = groupedByLocation[key];
    items.map((item,index) => {
        return (
        <>
        <Table>
         <TableRow>
          <TableCell>{key}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>{item.Name}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        </Table>
        </>
      )
    })
})


To achieve your goal of creating separate tables for each packingLocation, you can first filter the items by their packingLocation and then map through each filtered list to generate the corresponding table. Here's how you can modify your code:
  const locations = ['A', 'B']; // Add more locations as needed
    
    locations.map((location) => {
      const filteredItems = categorizedDatas2[key]?.items.filter(item => item.packingLocation === location);
    
      if (filteredItems.length > 0) {
        return (
          <Table key={location}>
            {filteredItems.map((item, index) => (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>{item.packingLocation}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>{item.Name}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </Table>
        );
      }
      return null;
    });


Use groupBy to get new object which has different key of the group attribute. Then use map to create the component.
{
  Object.entries(Object.groupBy(categorizedDatas2[key]?.items, ({ packingLocation }) => packingLocation)).map(([k, v]) =>
    v.map((item) => (
      <>
        <Table>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>{item.packingLocation}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>{item.Name}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </Table>
      </>
    ))
  );
}

